# How Can I Delete ALL emails from my iPhone Sent Folder?

Tags: iphone

How Can I Delete ALL emails from my iPhone Sent Folder - without doing one by one? I have somehow built up a couple thousand emails in my Sent Folder and need to know how to delete them all at once rather than one by one.

To the one reply so far:

I have the iPhone in my hand. When I click on the Mail icon, "My Email" opens up (it's the email set up thru iCloud with an xxxx@me.com address) When I go to "Mailboxes", the folders are - from top to bottom - Inbox, Draft, Sent, Junk, Trash, and Archive. So I don't know what you are talking about as MY iPhone clearly does have a "Sent Folder". I do NOT have Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook or any others set up on my iPhone - just the one set up thru iCloud.

Comment: The iPhone doesn't have a "Sent" folder.  Your mail service (gmail, yahoo, etc.) have the sent folders Mail apps like Mail, Outlook, or GMail just access the  sent folders.  Which app are you using?

Comment: I have the iPhone in my hand. When I click on the Mail icon, "My Email" opens up (it's the email set up thru iCloud with an xxxx@me.com address) When I go to "Mailboxes", the folders are - from top to bottom - Inbox, Draft, Sent, Junk, Trash, and Archive. So I don't know what you are talking about as MY iPhone clearly does have a "Sent Folder". I do NOT have Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook or any others set up on my iPhone - just the one set up thru iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> Go to your Sent folder
>
> Tap on the Edit Button on the top right
>
> Select the first email in your list
>
> Hold down the "Move" button
>
> While you are still holding the Move button, deselect the first email
>
> Put away all your fingers from the screen and wait a few seconds
>
> Now Mail asks you where to move All of your emails
>
> Select the Trash-Folder
>
> Inside the Trash Folder, you can delete all items at once

More details:

- https://www.imobie.com/support/delete-all-emails-iphone-ipad.htm

Comment: D'oh! Nuked my post since you answered simulaneously.  I will add that did this just yesterday (ios 12.1 on my iphone), and images for each step can be found here. https://www.imobie.com/support/delete-all-emails-iphone-ipad.htm

Comment: @RickBerge thanks for the link I added it. If you were going to post the same in sure it’s a good answer so please upvote :)

Comment: @user3439894 its a quotation but edited

Comment: It was not quote highlighted before, so it was something I though your wrote. BTW When I quote something to be used in an answer, I typically clean up any errors, technical and grammar, while noting such changes were made by me as appropriate.  In this case just cleaning up the crud is enough. :)